# Filter a multidimensional numpy array by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional numpy array and I only want specific values in each column of the array. If the vlaue does not match that of what I am filtering by I want to delete the entire row. Code snippet:

```
array = ([4, 78.01, 65.00, 98.00],
         [5, 23.08, 87.68, 65.3],
         [6, 45.98, 56.54, 98.76],
         [7, 98.23, 26.65, 46.56])
```

For example column 1 I would like numbers between 0-90 and column 4 I would want values between 70-100. So my ideal output would be:

```
 array = ([4, 78.01, 65.00, 98.00],
         [6, 45.98, 56.54, 98.76])
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain all conditions with `bitwise operators` and the perform boolean indexing:

```
array[(array[:,0] > 0) & (array[:,0] < 100) & (array[:,3] > 90) & (array[:,3] < 100)]

array([[ 4.  , 78.01, 65.  , 98.  ],
       [ 6.  , 45.98, 56.54, 98.76]])
```